# Was the ufotable Touhou anime ever released?

Tags: touhou-project, anime-tenchou

In order to celebrate the 10th anniversary of Anime Tenchou (who most notably appears in Lucky Star), ufotable animated a 10 minute crossover anime between Touhou and Anime Tenchou in 2010. ANN has a news release about it [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2010-09-24/touhou-project-anime-tenchou-get-anime-by-ufotable).

I know that this was shown at Animate Ichioshi Bishōjo Matsuri according to the news release, but I have not been able to find any information about a general release. Was this ever released in any format to the general public?

Comment: You could buy the a DVD of all 10 projects back in 2010, but it not available in stores nowadays.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To my knowledge, it has been released [but in a theater](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E5%BA%97%E9%95%B7%C3%97%E6%9D%B1%E6%96%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88) or the like and no one was allowed to record it in any way thus no one else has seen it.

> アニメ店長×東方プロジェクトとは、アニメ店長誕生10周年を記念して行われたコラボレーション企画である。
>
> [...]
>
> アニメ店長誕生から10周年を記念し製作されたショートアニメーション（約10分）で、2010年11月20日に行われた”『アニメ店長』プレゼンツ!!アニメイト一押し美少女アニメまつり”にて初公開された。
>
> [...]
>
> その後12月29日～31日にアニメイト一部店舗で単独イベント上映、2011年1月9日に全国アニメイト各店にて上映された。尚、DVD,BDの販売はなく（設定資料のみ販売）会場での上映限定での公開となった。

Comment: That is what I feared. Thanks. Hopefully it will be released in some other medium someday.

Comment: Is there any source to back up your post? (At least the part about it being released in the theatre)

Comment: @nhahtdh [This Niconicopedia article](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E5%BA%97%E9%95%B7%C3%97%E6%9D%B1%E6%96%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88) lists a number of occasions on which it was shown theatrically at special events. The article also states that the anime itself was not sold, and was only viewable at said events.

Comment: At the live stream of Machi★Asobi last year, Koyama from Animate along with Ufotable, [announced](http://blog.livedoor.jp/tohomemory/archives/45613750.html) the collaboration anime is undergoing packaging for distribution.
[Package Cover Art](https://twitter.com/ZAIDAN_K/status/651057558359142400?s=07)